# delimiter of tab '\t' of csv.writer in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to write the dict into csv as this form:

```
(column1)   (column2)
  aaa           1     
  bbb           2
```

but when I use the '\t' as the delimiter in the following code:

```
import csv

csv_filename = "test.csv"
dict = {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2} 
with open(csv_filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for key, value in dict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

I could not get the desired ouput, instead the created csv will be like

```
(column1)   (column2)
  aaa1
  bbb2
```

Comment: Are you opening the output file in Excel? What happens if you try to open the output file in a text editor, e.g. notepad?

Comment: This works. Don't see any issues in both Python 2 and 3

Comment: using a text editor it works, but is it true that opening with excel it will not recognize '\t'?

Comment: excel looks at the way the computer is set up to determine what the delimiter is, which in your case doesn't appear to be a tab, you can either change your computer settings, or use the data to columns function in excel.

Comment: Saving as a `.csv` file, Excel will assume it will be comma-delimited and is ignoring the tab. Try changing `csv_filename = "test.csv"` to `csv_filename = "test.txt"`, then open this file in Excel.

Comment: @asongtoruin not quite true, excel looks at the which locale you have set to determine the delimiter, the two I've found most often used by excel is comma or semicolon. it does not always assume comma.

Comment: @JamesKent you're right - I'm assuming UK settings. A semicolon will be assumed in locales where a comma is used as a decimal separator

Comment: @JamesKent you are right, now I changed the delimiter from tab to semicolon, in excel it works now, many thanks

Answer (score 15):

You are converting the output into a list which is combining the key and value.  Use the following instead.

```
import csv

csv_filename = "test.csv"
dict = {'aaa': 1, 'bbb': 2} 
with open(csv_filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(dict)
```