# Exporting data to a tabbed file from Django

Tags: python, django

I have exported a **.csv** file using the `csv` library of Python and it has a huge amount of columns and data that I want to be able to tab so its more easy to read.

Is there some kind of way to deal with this?

I'm guessing something like `writerow()` but for tabs?

For example:

Tab One: Name and Emails for people with more than 20 years

Tab Two: Name and Emails for people with more than 30 years

Tab Three: Name and Emails for people with more than 40 years

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45173678/5298150

Comment: I don't think that's what I want. I need to export the data to a file that has a function to create a tabbed interface, maybe not possible with csv but for other format.

Comment: Try https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/, that's what you need

Comment: thanks @crazychukz, will take a deeper look but that should work!