# Python - How to get the last element of a list (no commas provided)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working on a project with sensor data. I write the sensor data at first into a csv file to save it. After that I read the file and receive the sensor data as a list as follows:

```
[  0   1   1   0   0 516]
[  1   1   1   0   0 498]
[  2   1   1   0   0 499]
[  3   1   1   0   0 500]
[  4   1   1   0   0 487]
[  5   1   1   0   0 502]
...
```

There are no commas between the elements.
I need the last element of this list to transfer the unit (analog data).
I tested several things e.g. to create an array and convert it back to list and so on...

This is how I saved the data (working with a raspberry pi):

```
device.start(samplingRate, acqChannelsEDA)
    with open('/home/pi/pywork/EDAdata.csv', 'w') as edafile:
        # create csv writer
        writer = csv.writer(edafile)

        start = time.time()
        end = time.time()
        while (end - start) < running_time:
            # Read samples
            sampledata = device.read(nSamples)
           
            writer.writerow(sampledata)
            print(sampledata)
            # print(eda_tf)
            end = time.time()

    edafile.close()
```

The output for print(sampledata) is:

```
[[8 1 1 0 0 0]]
[[9 1 1 0 0 0]]
[[10  1  1  0  0  0]]
[[11  1  1  0  0  0]]
[[12  1  1  0  0  0]]
[[13  1  1  0  0  0]]
[[14  1  1  0  0  0]]
[[15  1  1  0  0  0]]
```

This is the code from `read(self, nSamples=100)`. The method to get `sampledata`.

```
 dataAcquired = numpy.zeros((nSamples, 5 + nChannels), dtype=int)
            for sample in range(nSamples):
                Data = self.receive(number_bytes)
                decodedData = list(struct.unpack(number_bytes * "B ", Data))
                crc = decodedData[-1] & 0x0F
                decodedData[-1] = decodedData[-1] & 0xF0
                x = 0
                for i in range(number_bytes):
                    for bit in range(7, -1, -1):
                        x = x << 1
                        if (x & 0x10):
                            x = x ^ 0x03
                        x = x ^ ((decodedData[i] >> bit) & 0x01)
                if (crc == x & 0x0F):
                    dataAcquired[sample, 0] = decodedData[-1] >> 4
                    dataAcquired[sample, 1] = decodedData[-2] >> 7 & 0x01
                    dataAcquired[sample, 2] = decodedData[-2] >> 6 & 0x01
                    dataAcquired[sample, 3] = decodedData[-2] >> 5 & 0x01
                    dataAcquired[sample, 4] = decodedData[-2] >> 4 & 0x01
                    if nChannels > 0:
                        dataAcquired[sample, 5] = ((decodedData[-2] & 0x0F) << 6) | (decodedData[-3] >> 2)
                    if nChannels > 1:
                        dataAcquired[sample, 6] = ((decodedData[-3] & 0x03) << 8) | decodedData[-4]
                    if nChannels > 2:
                        dataAcquired[sample, 7] = (decodedData[-5] << 2) | (decodedData[-6] >> 6)
                    if nChannels > 3:
                        dataAcquired[sample, 8] = ((decodedData[-6] & 0x3F) << 4) | (decodedData[-7] >> 4)
                    if nChannels > 4:
                        dataAcquired[sample, 9] = ((decodedData[-7] & 0x0F) << 2) | (decodedData[-8] >> 6)
                    if nChannels > 5:
                        dataAcquired[sample, 10] = decodedData[-8] & 0x3F
                else:
                    raise Exception(ExceptionCode.CONTACTING_DEVICE)
            
            return dataAcquired
```

Comment: If you want someone to help you - attach the code snippet which you use to save your sensor data into csv file. We are not magicians to get this information from the air :) Definitely, there are errors during saving data.

Comment: There is no list in what you show. Pls post an actual data structure.

Comment: can you print the type of sampledata and sampledata[0] ? `sampledata` should be a list of int, does not seems to be the case here. That's the problem. try to convert it first to a list of int.

Comment: you should also show your reading code

Comment: it looks like what you actually have is maybe "tab-separated values" data rather than "comma-separated values"... see here for how to read it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669947/delimiter-of-tab-t-of-csv-writer-in-python

Comment: @log0 Thank you! Where would you think I can change he list of int?

Comment: @AKR just before writerow. For me the problem is that you write one element per line (printing as [a b c d e]), instead of writing 5 int per lines. if you save the 5 int as a proper csv this will be easier on the reading side to use the csv reader and directly get a list of int (instead of a single element that you would have to split on the reader side).

Comment: @log0 makes sense, so can I change that in the read() function directly?

Answer (score 1):

To get last element of a list, you should use negative indexing, e.g.

```
arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
print (arr[-1])
print (arr[-2])
```

Output:

```
50
40
```

Comment: This is my problem, I can't get it like that bc there are no commas in between the elements, so it says the array / list is just onedimentsional..

Comment: @AKR can you run `type(<you-variable>)` to see its type? Then we can think about parsing it